# C# Https SSL Request Not Sending Properly

Tags: c#, ssl, https, request, httpwebrequest

I have some code using HttpWebRequests with several post requests via https. 
It works fine when it is run on Mac (using both .Net Core 2.0 and .Net 4.7), however when I run it on my Windows machine using .Net 4.7 the post requests execute fine however the server doesn't respond correctly (set a desired cookie). 
When I turn Charles SSL proxying on and run it (on Windows), the server responds correctly, as Charles is middle manning the request. This leads me to believe the problem is for some reason the SSL handshake isn't correct (e.g. wrong cipher being used) when the requests are sent without Charles running on Windows. I am still confused why it works on Mac but not Windows as it is the exact same code. If anyone knows how to make HttpWebRequest (or any other alternative way of sending requests in C#) have a proper SSL handshake/select the cipher it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it possible that the trusted root certificates differ between the Mac system and the Windows system?

Comment: @sedders123 Thanks for the suggestion, do you know how I would go about identifying the correct certificate?

Comment: Can you navigate to the site in a browser on both devices? If one of them displays warnings or errors saying that the website certificate is not trusted then that's a pretty good indicator.

Comment: Yes I can execute the posts requests in a browser and get the desired response on both Mac and Windows

Comment: Sounds like its not that. Only other thing I can think of is that the TLS version being used by the client is not supported by the server or vice versa. .NET Core may support different TLS versions to .NET framework?

Comment: That was my thoughts also and I checked however both the TLS version and the http version is the same all times.

Comment: Sorry that's all my ideas gone. An alternative, and newer, method of creating HTTP requests is the [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netframework-4.7.2) class.

Comment: Yeah I wrote an alternate version using HttpClient and unfortunately encountered the same issue. Thanks a lot for your time though